# Find number of similar elements in an RDD of (Array[Int] , Array[Int])

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of a tuple of Array[Int] and would like to know how many elements are similar in the Arrays, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of common element in array is a size of the set intersection:

```
rdd.map { case (x, y) =>  x.toSet.intersect(y.toSet).size }
```